# If I type an address in a dialog box, is the website owner notified of the text?

Tags: search, dialog, box

If a type in a dialog box on a website, is the owner of the website able to access the text? Note I have not submitted the page or draft in any way.
Furthermore if the dialog box is a address bar and comes up with address suggestions and I pick one is the owner of the website able to access this information? Note I have also not submitted the page or draft here.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by dialog box input fields inside an HTML page, then the frontend code can listen to changes on the input fields, while you are typing and send that information to the backend. Nothing stops the frontend code from doing that, so it is possible.